# Backend container can't connect to database - Sequelize, Node, Postgres, Docker

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

When I try to connect my backend (using Sequelize) I get this following error:

```
error ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/app
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: server
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/src/app
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ckl
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `127.0.0.1` implies to me that it is attempting to connect to itself, instead of anther container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your backend is connecting to the db you should add a `depends_on`:

```
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: server
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/src/app
```

The db will now be accessible at the host `db:5432` if your application is configured to connect to `localhost:5432` or `172.0.0.1:5432` you'll need to replace the hostname `localhost` with `db`. Your postgres connection string might also not have a host and might be trying to connect to localhost by default. Should be able to look at sequelize to figure out how to pass a host.

Comment: Nice, please make sure to accept the answer as correct :)

Comment: Thank you so much, had been breaking my head on this issue for the past few hours. :))